# Scrape instance of Youtube verified badge using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube, youtube-api

I've been trying to check from a youtube video link that the channel/uploader is verified (blue badge). Seems like Youtube API doesn't have functionality for this, so I've been trying to scrape using `BeautifulSoup`. Here is what I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_id
source = requests.get(url).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    
# does not work
bs.find_all("div", {"class": "badge badge-style-type-verified style-scope ytd-badge-supported-renderer"})
```

I tried tracing the hierarchy of the HTML elements leading to the `ytd-badge` class and I found this by inspecting:

html -> body -> ytd-app -> #content -> #page-manager -> ytd-watch-flexy -> #columns -> #primary -> div#primary-inner.style-scope.ytd-watch-flexy -> #meta -> #meta-content -> ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer.style-scope.ytd-watch-flexy -> #container -> div.#top-row.style-scope.ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer -> ytd-video-owner-renderer -> div.#upload-info.style-scope.ytd-video-owner-renderer -> #channel-name ->  ytd-badge-supported-renderer.style-scope.ytd-channel-name

It's pretty long and crazy so I was wondering how I could access it? Is there an easier way to accomplish this using Python? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `youtube-dl` instead of scraping youtube?

Comment: Keep in mind that Youtube pages are largely rendered client side and the file you get back is mostly data. You probably could just search the file for the JSON val/prop string that indicates a verified user.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube uses JavaScript, so use [Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) to scrape the page.

Install it using `pip install requests-html`.

Since there are multiple videos on the webpage which can have the badge, we need the check if the class which contains the badge (`badge badge-style-type-verified style-scope ytd-badge-supported-renderer`) exists under the channel's info class (`style-scope ytd-video-owner-renderer`).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

video_id = ""
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_id
# Initialize an HTML Session
session = HTMLSession()
# Get the html content
response = session.get(video_url)
# Execute JavaScript
response.html.render(sleep=3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")

# Find the channel info class
channel_info = soup.select_one('.style-scope ytd-video-owner-renderer')

# Check if the class that contains the verified badge exists in the channel info class
if channel_info.find('div', class_='badge badge-style-type-verified style-scope ytd-badge-supported-renderer'):
    print('Verified')
else:
    print('NOT verified!')
```